# How can I get the IResource associated with the propertyChanged event in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, resources, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am developing an Eclipse plugin that monitors events in the workspace. One of my classes implements IPropertyListener which means that it inherits the propertyChanged method. This method gets fired when a file in the plugin's workspace gets dirtied. I need to know what IResource is associated with the propertyChanged event but my current implementation isn't working.

```
public void propertyChanged(Object source, int propId)
{
    if(propId == IEditorPart.PROP_DIRTY)
    {
        IResource resource = (IResource)source;
    }
}
```

I think this isn't working because source is not of type IResource, but I don't know how else to get at the resource associated with this property change.

Any ideas of how I would get at the IResource?

Comment: What type is source? You will likely need to use the API of that class to retrieve associated IResource.

Comment: In WorkbenchPart there is the firePropertyChanged method which calls propertyChanged. It uses WorkbenchPart.this as the source param. This extends EventManager. I don't think that route is going to get me the resource, I am wondering if there is some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try casting source to IEditorPart. Then call getEditorInput(). Not all editor inputs are workspace resources, so check for one of the sub-types (probably FileEditorInput) and go from there.

Alternatively, just listen to resource changes yourself via IWorkspace.addResourceChangeListener() instead of relying on a third party.